# Comparing how "high" the ordinals go in one model of ZFC versus another.

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Given two transitive models of ZFC, is there a way of comparing how "high" the ordinals go in one model versus another?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $M_1$ and $M_2$ are two transitive models of ZFC, then $\mathsf{Ord}^{M_1}$ and $\mathsf{Ord}^{M_2}$ are actually two ordinals $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$.

Since those are ordinals, we can compare them and see which one is larger (or if they are equal).

Comment: Oh. Are "transitive model" and "inner model" synonymous then? I assumed the latter was a stronger condition than the former.

Comment: No. Standard models are *sets*, inner models are *proper classes*. But we first **fix** one universe to be the background universe we work in, then inner models are transitive subclasses containing all the ordinals and satisfy the axioms of ZFC; standard models are *sets* which are transitive (or isomorphic to a transitive set) and satisfy the axioms of ZFC.

Comment: Yes but is there a difference between a "transitive model" and an "inner model"?

Comment: @user18921: Transitive model usually refers to a set, inner model is a transitive *proper class* containing all the ordinals.